# How to send selected lnbox mail as a attachment through outlook addins using Atl/Com project in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, outlook-addin

the following is my code:

```
_ApplicationPtr pApp(Application);
_MailItemPtr pNewMailItem;
pApp->CreateItem(olMailItem,(IDispatch**)&pNewMailItem);
pNewMailItem->put_BCC(L"mailid1");
pNewMailItem->put_Body(L"Mail Send from Visual C++/ATL");
pNewMailItem->put_To(L"mailid2");    
pNewMailItem->Send();
```

I am able to send a new mail but not getting how to attach the selected inbox mail .

Please suggest me some references for proceeding further.

Answer (score 0):

To attach an email you need to access the handle to the `Attachments`object associated with your `MailItem` object, and attach your file with a call to `Attachments::Add`.

Here's a minimal working example.  I haven't tested this particular code, so consider a kind of pseudo-code:

```
_ApplicationPtr pApp(Application);
_MailItemPtr pNewMailItem;
pApp->CreateItem(olMailItem,(IDispatch**)&pNewMailItem);

Outlook::AttachmentsPtr pAttachments;
pNewMailItem->get_Attachments(&pAttachments);

// you need to specify your own values for these parameters
ATL::CComVariant filePath(someFilePath);
ATL::CComVariant displayName("some name");
ATL::CComVariant type(Outlook::olByValue);   // to attach a copy
ATL::CComVariant position(1); // add as 1st attachment

Outlook::AttachmentPtr pAttachment;
pAttachments->Add(filePath, displayName, type, position, &pAttachment);
```